# Replacing a sequence in a string with its match index

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, If I am replacing "a" in a string "a b a b a b c", how do I get it to replace with the index of the match (i.e. "1 b 2 b 3 b c")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'a b a ba a';
$count = 1;
while(($letter_pos = strpos($str, 'a')) !== false) {
    $str = substr_replace($str, $count++, $letter_pos, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead.

PHP 5.3.0 example (not tested):

```
$i = 0;
preg_replace_callback("/a/", function( $match ) {
    global $i;
    return ++$i;
}, "a b a b a b c");
```

Comment: not gonna work because of the scope. should be `function() { static $i = 0; return ++$i; }` or `... global $i; return ++$i;...`

Comment: I changed in answer, global by static, to make work it properly

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need preg_*?

Here is how I would do it:

```
$numerals = range(1, 10);
$str = str_replace('a', $numerals, $str);
```

The sadly neglected and often ignored str_replace() function can accept arrays as arguments. In case an array is passed as the second argument, it changes every occurrence of the search string with the corresponding array's element.

Comment: How come I get an array to string conversion error when I try this code?

Comment: This does not work.If the first parameter (`$search`) isn't an array the second paramter ($replace) is always converted to string.  see http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/string.c?view=log